# How to hide methods while documenting using VSDocMan?

Tags: c#, documentation

I'm using VSDocMan for generating help document.

Consider I'm having following methods

- Method 1
- Method 2
- Method 3

But I want to include methods(Method1 & method3 only) in my documentation.
Is there any option in VSDocMan to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. I found answer...

If we use the tag **compilewhen = never**, the method will not be included in the documentation...

```
/// <compilewhen>never</compilewhen>
public void Method2()
{
}
```